# Xcode 4.5.2: How to correctly program a CGRectMake?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, landscape

I want a view, which is in LANDSCAPE mode, to move up when a textField is being edited (because it is covered by the keyboard), the problem is that I'm not setting correctly the coordinates because the view moves to the left instead of going up, it seems as X values were changed by Y values and voiceovers. What am I doing wrong? How can I get it solved? Is there any special code for LANDSCAPE mode?

CODE:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -160, 300, 480);
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Are you sure it moves left, or did you mean `480, 300)`?

Comment: yes it moves to the left, the code is a copy paste so it is exactly what I wrote

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because those look like Portrait proportions.

Comment: Sorry Sorry Sorry!!!! you are right!! sorry! I did not noticed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often the most tedious mistakes are the ones we never look for. :P

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -160, 480, 300);
```